# how can I use a matrix when I need a vector?

Tags: c#

I have to make an iterpolation fo f(x,y) so I have a double[,].
For the bicubic spline interpolation I uses alglib.

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    //
    // We use bilinear spline to interpolate f(x,y)=x^2+2*y^2 sampled 
    // at (x,y) from [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] X [0.0, 1.0].
    //
    double[] x = new double[]{0.0,0.5,1.0};
    double[] y = new double[]{0.0,1.0};
    double[] f = new double[]{0.00,0.25,1.00,2.00,2.25,3.00};
    double vx = 0.25;
    double vy = 0.50;
    double v;
    double dx;
    double dy;
    double dxy;
    alglib.spline2dinterpolant s;

    // build spline
    alglib.spline2dbuildbicubicv(x, 3, y, 2, f, 1, out s);

    // calculate S(0.25,0.50)
    v = alglib.spline2dcalc(s, vx, vy);
```

As you see in the arguments of alglib.spline2dbuildbicubicv f is a double[]. I need to apply it with may f double[,].

How can I solve this?